# curl HTTP POST with Dictionary Data not working

Tags: http, curl, google-cloud-data-fusion

Friends,

I am trying to execute below curl command to get response, but it is giving error.

```
REQUEST_BODY='{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": "eexxxx", "client_secret": "4pyxxxx"}'

curl --request POST --url 'https://mylearning.technologies.com/auth/oauth2/token' \
-H 'accept: application/json' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d "$REQUEST_BODY"
```

Error: `bad request grant type can not be null`

However, when I am running the below command with same credentials it is working fine and giving me right response.

```
curl --request POST --url 'https://mylearning.technologies.com/auth/oauth2/token' \
-H 'accept: application/json' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d grant_type=client_credentials -d client_id=eexxxx \
-d client_secret=4pyxxxx
```

Please advise.

Thanks,
Santanu